# RadComboBoxItems not being added to multiple RadComboBoxes

Tags: asp.net, combobox, telerik

All I'm really trying to do is populate three different comboboxes with the same item.  When this code executes below only one combobox is getting the values.  Any help is welcomed.  Thanks!

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            RadComboBoxItem li = new RadComboBoxItem();
            li.Text = i.ToString();
            li.Value = i.ToString();
            InputPairThousandValueComboBox.Items.Add(li);
            InputUsertThousdandValueComboBox.Items.Add(li);
            InputCurrentlyListedThousdandComboBox.Items.Add(li);

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find anything in the Telerik docs that says this explicitly, but it appears a single instance of a `RadComboBoxItem` can only be contained in a *single* `RadComboBox`; you can't share a `RadComboBoxItem` between controls.

[The docs](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/p_telerik_web_ui_radcomboboxitem_owner.html) do hint to this: the `RadComboBoxItem` has an 'owner' property that is a reference to the `RadComboBox` that contains the item (implying that there can be only 1 owner)

Under the covers, the second & third `Add(...)` calls most likely first remove the item from the combo box its already in.

So, you'll have to create a separate `RadComboBoxItem` for each `RadComboBox`.  Here's one way you could do it using the `RadComboBoxItem` constructor that takes the text and value as arguments.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   var val = i.ToString();
   InputPairThousandValueComboBox.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem(val, val));
   InputUsertThousdandValueComboBox.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem(val, val));
   InputCurrentlyListedThousdandComboBox.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem(val, val));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those still running into this issue, a way I found is adding the items as a dictionary, then binding with a datasource. 
[link to telerik form](https://www.telerik.com/forums/add-items-with-value-and-display-into-comboboxes#sYg6UJrNhEmqdttYv7KUBQ/)

```
    Dictionary<string, string> comboSource = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    comboSource.Add("", "");
    comboSource.Add(user.Rs.GetString("txtDate"), "phDate");
    comboSource.Add(user.Rs.GetString("txtBranch"), "mhBranch");
    comboSource.Add(user.Rs.GetString("txtDepartmentCode"), "mhDepartmentCode");
    comboSource.Add(user.Rs.GetString("txtLocationCode"), "mhLocationCode");
    comboSource.Add(user.Rs.GetString("txtModelCode"), "mhModel");
    comboSource.Add(user.Rs.GetString("txtProductCode"), "phProductCode");
    comboSource.Add(user.Rs.GetString("txtShiftCode"),"shShiftCode");
    comboSource.Add(user.Rs.GetString("txtSubcategory"),"phSubcategory");

    cboSort1.DataSource = cboSort2.DataSource = cboSort3.DataSource = cboSort4.DataSource = comboSource;
    cboSort1.DataTextField = cboSort2.DataTextField = cboSort3.DataTextField = cboSort4.DataTextField = "Key";
    cboSort1.DataValueField = cboSort2.DataValueField = cboSort3.DataValueField = cboSort4.DataValueField = "Value";
    cboSort1.DataBind();
    cboSort2.DataBind();
    cboSort3.DataBind();
    cboSort4.DataBind();
```